# How to remove specific keys from a wordlist?

Tags: debian, text-processing

I have generated a wordlist of keys starting from 03000000000 and ends at 03999999999 through crunch.

So what I want is to delete a specific number of keys from it, for example, I want to delete keys starting from 03509999999 to 03999999999.

So I am wondering how to do that easily. As the wordlist file is 12 GB, I can't even open it to do that manually but rather I would prefer to do that through some easy commands in the terminal.

I have Kali Linux.

Comment: A better approach would have been to exclude that range from being generated to save time and disk space.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the words are one on a line and sorted you can do:

```
head --lines 509999999 input_file
```

If the file looks like:

```
03000000000 03509999998 03509999999 03510000000 03999999998
03000000001 03999999999 03000000002
```

(i.e. unsorted and multiple entries on a line) you can use the following python
program:

```
import sys

def read(fp):
    buf = ""
    while True:
        if ' ' in buf or '\n' in buf:
            try:
                word, buf = buf.split(None, 1)
            except ValueError:
                word, buf = buf.strip(), ""
            if word:
                yield word
        if not buf:
            buf = fp.read(100)
        if not buf:
            yield None

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    for x in read(fp):
       if x is None:
           break
       if sys.argv[2] <= x <= sys.argv[3]:
           continue
       print x
```

start with `python test.py inputfile 03509999999 03999999999`. The output will be the words in the same order as in the original but all will be newline separated.

Comment: Yes...each word is on one line...

Comment: I am a beginner how will it remove those lines from wordlist file namely as hunter-wordlist

Answer (score 0):

If words are located each per line then you could use awk,

```
awk '$0 >= 03509999999 && $0 <= 03999999999 {next;}{print}' file
```

Comment: Where I have to mention the file name please in the awk code you have provided?

Comment: in the place of file. `awk '$0 >= 03509999999 && $0 <= 03999999999 {next;}{print}' infile > outfile`